# Unable to render panelGroup when commandButton is clicked (JSF)

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have been trying to create a popup with a panelGroup I successfully did one but each time I  click the commandButton which is suppose to render the panelGroup, it reloads the whole page and so I decided to use ajax. I want the panelGroup to be rendered each time I click a commandButton but it gives me an error saying: “malformedXml:during update:j_idt8:comp1 not found”

Here is my code:

```
<h:form>
<h:commandButton value="Show Popup" action="#{popupBean.open}">
<f:ajax event="action" render="comp1"/>
</h:commandButton>
<div style="position:absolute;top:200px;left:500px; background-color:palevioletred;height:50%; width:50%">
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{popupBean.popupStatus}" id="comp1">

<h:panelGroup>
<div align="center" class="popupBody"><font size="2" style="position:relative; top:5px">
 <table id="appDetails" width="270px">

 <tr>
                                                         <td width="165px">Appliance Name:&nbsp;</td><td><h:outputText value="Galaxy Tab"/></td>
                                                 </tr>
                                                     <tr>

 <td>Available.    Quantity:&nbsp;<td><td><h:outputText value="300" /></td>
                                                 </tr>
                                                 <tr>
                                                     <td>Price:&nbsp;</td><td><h:outputText value="64,000" /></td>
                                                 </tr>
                                                 <tr>
                                                     <td>Discount:&nbsp;</td><td><h:outputText value="10,000" /></td>
                                                 </tr>
                                                 <tr>
                                                     <td>Amount:&nbsp;</td><td><h:outputText value="54,000" /></td>
                                                 </tr>
                                             </table>

</font>
                <br/><br/>
```

```
<h:panelGroup>
<div class="popupheader" >
<div class="title"><h:outputText.    value="Details"/></div>
<div class="button"><h:commandButton styleClass="closeButton" actionListener="#{popupBean.close}" 
                                                               alt="close" style="border:1;"/></div>
</div>
</h:panelGroup>

</h:panelGroup>
</div>
</h:form>
```

Here is my managed bean:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;

/**
 *
 * @author DavidLaxi
 */
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped

public class PopupBean implements Serializable{
 int track; 
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
boolean popupStatus = false;
public static int count = 0;

public PopupBean() {
 count  ;
 setTrack(count);
}
public void setTrack(int track){
this.track = track;
}
public int getTrack(){
return track;
}
public void setPopupStatus(boolean popupStatus){
this.popupStatus=popupStatus;
}
public boolean getPopupStatus(){
return popupStatus;
}
public void open(){

setPopupStatus(!popupStatus);
}
public void close(){
setPopupStatus(false);
}
}
```

Please I really need help on this.

Comment: You should try: 
`<h:panelGroup id="comp1"><h:panelGroup rendered="#{popupBean.popupStatus}">Your code...<h:panelGroup><h:panelGroup>`

Comment: If you want more help, take the time to create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), by removing all those unnecessary divs, styles, getters, setters, and keeping only the minimum amount of code that is enough to replicate the issue. And also fix code indentation, too.

Answer (score 0):

Hurray!! Thank GOD I have found the answer,  all I was suppose to do was to use ajax to render the form instead of the panelGroup.

E.g

```
<h:form id="formval1">
  <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{managedBean}">
<f:ajax event="action" render="formval1"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

......All other stuffs.....

Thanks to everyone for your help and concern, I appreciate.